# Update JLabel when custom object property changes

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, propertychangelistener, propertychangesupport

I have a Java class and I want one of its properties to be displayed by a JLabel in a Swing desktop application:

```
class Item {
    private String name;
    private Integer quantity;

    // getters, setters...
}

class Frame {
    Item item = new Item();
    ...

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText(item.getQuantity().toString());
    ...
}
```

How do I get the label to update its text whenever the quantity property changes on the item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something will have to update the text of your label (with the `setText` method you already know). Probably the easiest thing is to let the `Item` class fire `PropertyChangeEvent`s when its properties are changed, and attach a listener to the item which updates the label.

```
final JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText(item.getQuantity().toString());
item.addPropertyChangeListener( new PropertyChangeListener(){
   @Override
   public void propertyChange( PropertyChangeEvent event ){
     if ( "quantity".equals( event.getPropertyName ) ){
        //I assume this happens on the EDT, otherwise use SwingUtilities.invoke*
        label.setText( (String)event.getNewValue() );
     }
   }
});
```

The `PropertyChangeSupport` class makes it easy to manage the listeners and fire the events in your `Item` class

Answer (score 0):

By calling repaint() which is inhereted from Component.

Comment: If it was possible I'd like to avoid calling anything. Is it possible to use custom events or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably add an ObjectChangeListener to your Item object, then override it's objectChanged method to update the JLabel and call repaint().